# Prepopulated SMS text getting truncated after certain character(s).

Tags: html, django-templates, sms

My mobile site uses a simple html tag to enable the user to call their mobile's SMS app from their mobile browser: `<a href="sms:1234567?body=hello world">Send SMS</a>`This prepopulates the body of the messages with 'hello world' and the phone number field with '1234567'.

But I've noticed that if the body contains **#**, the text beyond the **#** gets truncated. For instance if the text is `<a href="sms:1234567?body=hello #world">Send SMS</a>`only 'hello' prepopulates in the body of the text.

Can anyone shed light on why this happens, and whether there's a way to circumvent this?

Thanks.

Comment: # is a URL Fragment Identifier and as such has special meaning, you need to apply URL Encoding and put the encoded string in the anchor; `body=hello%20%23world` (You should do this as routine)

Comment: To be exact, I'm using a Django template tag in the body. My code is `<a href="sms:+92123?body={{ descriptionwithurl }}">SMS</a>`.

Comment: Found it. Needed to add |urlencode within the Django tag to follow your instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Alex K's response in the comments, I needed to apply URL encoding. I'm writing a Django app, so in my case, I did the following:`<a href="sms:+92123?body={{ description|urlencode }}">SMS</a>`